# JAXB empty node in bindings

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb2, xjc

`JAXB` can't parse the bindings for this example:

```
<xs:element name="classA" type="classA" substitutionGroup="classSubA"/>

<xs:complexType name="complexClassA" mixed="true">

<xs:attribute name="attA">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <moProperty value="classA:attA"/>
            <label value="Attribute A" default="true"/>
            <externAccess value="readWrite"/>
            <description value="NO COMMENTS"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="off"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="on"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

And the `bindings.xml` (fragment):

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema/mySchema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='complexClassA']">
            <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='attA']">
                <jxb:property name="att" />
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

When generating the Java files the error is:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: XPath evaluation of ".//xs:element[@name='attA']" results in empty target node
```

What I'm overlooking?

Thank you.

Udo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this:

```
<jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='attA']">
```

Should be this:

```
<jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='attA']">
```

You have an attribute, XPath applies to an element.